# How to remove image space in bootstrap panel

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I searched and tried a lot of time but in vain
my images takes more space than the image width have.
When I inspect the images on the website it seems that it takes more space in the width than the image width...(It seems that it is the margin) but when I try removing it in CSS with putting margin to zero but still the same

[image]

here is my index code:

```
<% else %>
<%= render 'form' %>
<div class="row">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><%= post.description %></p>
                    <%= image_tag(post.image.url(:large), class: "img-responsive" ) %><br/>
                    <% if post.user == current_user %>
                        <div><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %> | <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delet, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %> </div><br/>
                    <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

here is an image of my problem:

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/i0TI9">
    <a href="//imgur.com/i0TI9"></a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: can we see your CSS code

Comment: it works with width: 100% as the answers suggets below...thank u anyway

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the `img` width to `100%` and make `overflow:hidden`

This will help you surely.

Comment: Thank you...It is working now but why we need to add overflow: hidden; here??It seems to work without adding it

Comment: as said .img-responsive class in bootstrap do that work for you.

Comment: Thank you...get it

Answer (score 2):

The `.img-responsive` class in Bootstrap will only prevent images from overflowing their container at smaller sizes - it will not ensure that smaller images expand to fill their containers.

You have two options:

1. Use larger images - large enough to ensure that the image always fills it's container (easily achieved with Bootstrap's grid).
2. Set the images to `width: 100%;`, although the downside here is that images will begin to blur or pixelate if increased beyond their natural dimensions.